# Codeigniter CSS not being applied to html view pages

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, view

The css is not being applied to the html views in my codeigniter project. Everything else seems to be working fine.

One answer on StackOverflow suggested removing the ?= base_url() ? part , which I Have tried but that doesn't work either,

This is the head.php file in templates, which contains the css.

Where else could the problem lie?

```
<head>
    <?php require_once("meta.php"); ?>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

I have tried removing the base part, but that doesn't work either.

```
<head>
    <?php require_once("meta.php"); ?>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>resource/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="resource/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="resource/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resource/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Btw you have **too many unclosed questions** and if made it a habit nobody will be encouraged to answer your questions anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recheck your configs and make sure you set your `base_url` correctly in your `config.php` so it would be something like that:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/';
```

enable `mod_rewrite` and make sure your `.htaccess` is in your `FCPATH` and is as simple as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

finally remove your `index.php` in your `config.php` if you are not using it like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and your ready to go, load the `url_helper` in your controller:

```
$this->load->helper(['url']);
```

now you can use `base_url` correctly wherever you want:

```
<link href="<?= base_url('resource/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Just make sure that this path is correct and `inspect>console` in your browser to see if it is loaded.